# C++ Will Valgrind detect leftover allocated memory as leaked?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing in a program using C++ that requires dynamic memory that I allocate using new. I have a case in which the user can close the program, but I didn't include delete for all of the leftover memory.

Note: This memory is tracked by a list of object pointers that all exist at the time of closing, thus no memory is 'lost.

Will valgrind assume that leftover memory is leaked memory if I don't clean up the array before closing?

On other concern is, if I /do/ loop through my object array and delete all of the memory before the program closes, will Valgrind be able to determine if any memory was leaked?

**EDIT**

I did loop through and freed all of the memory and now Valgrind says I have no leak. Can this be trusted?

Comment: If you manually allocate memory, you'll have to delete it manually (unless using smart pointers). I removed the C tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leak memory, you leak memory, and valgrind will (usually) detect and report it.  Holding onto pointers until program termination is not good enough (to convince valgrind).  If you really, really need to do something like that, you can instead use a "pool" (e.g. `Boost.Pool`) to allocate from, then at the end of your program just deallocate the entire pool at once.

Since you've already said you have a solution where you loop and delete everything, great.  Just keep it that way.  If you end up with a performance problem on shutdown, consider the pool approach.